# Javascript directly call modal?

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling

With the below code I can pop up a modal when I click the logo.
How would I do the same thing but instead call it directly from within an event listener?

```
    <div class="logo-brand header sidebar rows">
        <div class="logo">
            <h1><a href="#fakelink" class="md-trigger" data-modal="logout-modal"><img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="Logo"> SAMPLE NAME</a></h1>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I want to call it from within the listener:

```
           var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
            map: map,
            });
            marker.addListener('click', function() {
            // I want the dialog to show from here...

            });
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using these? 

$('#myModal').modal('toggle');
$('#myModal').modal('show');
$('#myModal').modal('hide')